# Using xsi:nil in XML

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xsd, xml-nil

I am generating an XML file from a VB.NET app.  The document was generating fine before I tried to add nillable elements.  I am now testing putting in just one nil element as:

```
<blah xsi:nil="true"></blah>
```

Once this element is in place and I try to view the XML file in IE it is unable to display.  I am receiving:

> The XML page cannot be displayed 
>   Cannot view XML input using XSL style
>   sheet. Please correct the error and
>   then click the Refresh button, or try
>   again later.
>
> ---
>
> The operation completed successfully.
>   Error processing resource

If I remove this one element it displays fine again.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you post your XSD and sample XML?

Comment: If you work a lot with XML in the browser, my advice is to get a recent version of Opera. it has got by far the most informational error messages for XML/XSLT related problems. Load your XML inn opera, then do Menu>tools>advanced>error console. 

you'll get good messages, line numbers and column numbers. Much better XML support than either IE or FF or chrome or safari.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` to declare the `xsi` namespace set on the root element of your XML?